# How to remove part of file name characters by string including files in subfolders in CMD

Tags: string, batch-file, cmd, command, prompt

i need your help.
I'm creating this batch file to change or remove various files names in various subfolders
of the specific directory. but the command have a problem... look this:

```
Set remove_me=Picture
set extension=.jpeg
set mydir="C:\users\user\Pictures\news"
```

this folder and subfolders contents:

```
DCIM_0001.Picture.jpeg
DCIM_0002.Picture.jpeg
DCIM_0003.Picture.jpeg
```

...

The Command:

```
for /R %mydir% %%a in (*%remove_me%*%extension%) do (set name=%%a)
```

now, i have the full directory of each file

example: C:\users\user\Pictures\news\DCIM_0001.Picture.jpeg (its my string "Name")

Removing the caracteres "Picture" of file name

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set new_name=!name:%remove_me%=!
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
```

Results: C:\users\user\s\news\DCIM_0001..jpeg

i want:  C:\users\user\Pictures\news\DCIM_0001..jpeg (to edit only the file name)

its possible?
i think that if i export the string to another file .txt and get it back, but don't have any idea for this momment.

Comment: Separate file path from name  using [parameter extensions](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) i.e. `set filename=%%~na`, `set filepath=%%~dpa` and `set fileext=%%~xa` and  `call set new_filename=!filename:%remove_me%=!`. Then, fully qualified path fo a file should be `set new_name=!filepath!!new_filename!!fileext!`

Comment: thank you very much!